# Execute Pyinstaller oin Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, pyinstaller

When I do the following from the terminal:

```
   pyinstaller Script.py
```

It works. But the same command in Jenkins doesn't and throws the following error:

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/abderrahmen/.local/bin/pyinstaller", line 7, in <module>
>         from PyInstaller.__main__ import run ImportError: No module named PyInstaller.__main__ 
>     Build step 'Exécuter un script shell'
>     marked build as failure
```

Any ideas? I am on Ubuntu18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most Linux-based platforms, the name of the Python 3 binary is `python3` (or perhaps a minor version like `python36` or `python3.6` though this would  not be the case on Ubuntu).

Aliases are ignored in scripts by default, though you can force it; but a better solution is to wrap the binary with a function instead of an alias.

```
python () { python3 "$@"; }
```

(Simply spelling out `python3` instead of `python` is probably better still, unless you need to cope with platforms where the name might be different.)

`sudo` in a Jenkins script looks odd indeed; perhaps you would instead like to create a virtual environment in your Jenkins build script. This allows you to install, as a regular user, any packages you need, without interfering with system-wide packages or other build jobs at all.

Comment: Actually I am not trying to execute **python** command on a script. I am trying to execute **pyinstaller** that calls python. But in my Jenkins pyinstaller keeps on using python2.

Comment: Where is `pyinstaller` installed and where does it look for the module? Installing it in a virtualenv should give you better control over these things, too.

Comment: The edit doesn't really provide anything new. What does `/home/abderrahmen/.local/bin/pyinstaller` contain, is it a script which has a shebang? Pointing where? What's the value of `sys.path` inside this script, if indeed it is a script? And finally, why do you insist on using this instead of installing a fresh, disentangled copy in a virtual environment?